# Can't get ImageMagick to process uploaded images using paperclip

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip, archlinux

When I upload images I am getting the following error:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20091218-7204-1fuv2j1-0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I have staging servers that have been setup on VMs that work fine, but once I move out to the production server this is what I get.  All servers are running on Archlinux, although the staging servers are on 64bit OS's while the production is an a 32bit.

If I run:

```
identify -version
```

I get an error until I add the /usr/local/bin to the PATH, to which I will then see the ImageMagick specs. Unfortunately, altering the PATH doesn't seem to have any effect when uploading files directly to the server.

I have also been unsucessful when setting the location paperlclip looks for the image lib via:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin/'
end
```

Any clues on how to configure things to allow imagemagick to process the images?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the png and jpeg delegates weren't available when compiling the IM.  After downloading and installing the delegates, then re-compiling IM things are now working.